# Can we put navigationcontroller in MasterView in iPad Application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail

I have worked mostly on iPhone apps. Now I need to build an iPad app. In that I need to put NavigationController in the MasterView of the Master Detail View of the iPad as we do in the UITableView in the iPhone. I mean when user selects a particular row it should navigate to another tableview with newly filled data. and user can go to the previous by pressing back button. Also On each selection I need to make change of image in the detail view.

I dont have any idea to achieve this.

Please provide any suggestions or any sample code for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these Tutorials :-

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

These will help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this in your appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

    self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationControlle, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible. There are no limitations on what you can display in the master and detail views of a split view controller.

Think of the split view as merely a view that displays two of your view controllers. They can contain anything.

If I understood what you're trying to achieve correctly then what you want to do is create a View Controller with a UITableView which will display the data in the left column. This View Controller should also have a UINavigationController which will push another view controller when you select something in the table.

So far, so good. Nothing has changed in the detail view since it in reality isn't aware of or connected to the master view in any way. When the user has moved enough steps down in the master view, and you want to change the detail view - then you can set the viewControllers-property of the navigation controller to update the detail view with whichever view controller you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Apple has provided a sample code called [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775)

It shows how communication is done between master and detail using delegation.